# how to get matches drawn by "drawMatches" in an array (for example in a DMatch structure)?

Tags: opencv, surf, sift

I know that drawMatches function does not show all of the matches of its matches1to2 parameter. This is based on its other parameters and flags (e.g. "do not show single lines"). I am wondering is there any way to get access to the output matches (the matches that drawMatches displays) in an array format (e.g. DMatch structure)? If so, how? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't get your question. You have you give the two `vector<KeyPoint>` and the `vector<vector<DMatch>>` as input to `drawMatches`, which only draws the input. Why would you need to get a `DMatch` array as output ?

Comment: Thanks AldurDisciple. I tried to draw matches using (vector<vector<DMATCH> matches1to2> (the same vector as what I used as the input argument of the "drawMatches" function) myselft, without using the "drawMatches" function. But it was much different from the output of "drawMatches". mine contained a lot of lines in contrast to drawMatches' that contained only a few lines.

Comment: From what I can read in the documentation, `drawMatches` always draw all the matches, and the options and flags are related to the drawing of keypoints. Maybe the implementation you made had a bug ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for

---

```
for (std::vector<cv::DMatch>::const_iterator it= Matches.begin();it!= Matches.end(); ++it){
    float x= keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.x;
    float y= keypoints1[it->queryIdx].pt.y;
    circle( copy, Point2f(x,y), 2, Scalar(255,255,255), -1, 8, 0 );
    points1.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));

    x= keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.x;
    y= keypoints2[it->trainIdx].pt.y;
    points2.push_back(cv::Point2f(x,y));
}
```

---

`points1` and `points2` will thus represent keypoints which match